# わからなくなってしまう Iｍ confused

Tags: questions

発音は全部「んー」ですね。でも、書くときにわからなくなってしまうので「うん」、「ううん」、「うーん」と書きます。

What does わからなくなってしまう mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> わからなくなってしまう

わかる -- dictionary form -- to understand.

わからない -- negative form -- to not understand, to be incomprehensible.

わからなく -- continuative form of わからない -- you need this form to use なる.

わからなくなる -- to become incomprehensible.

わからなくなってしまう -- verb in te-form + しまう -- to end up doing verb

Altogether:

> To end up becoming incomprehensible.